# Are SSL Certificates personal or global?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https, certificate

I'm wondering i export the certificate of a website will it get exported with some of my personal info?

Basically I'm working on a cURL script and other people are gonna use it too so the following would not be the best option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

So i came across a guide on how to verify the certificate and it says i need to export it and attach those lines to my code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/BuiltinObjectToken-EquifaxSecureCA.crt");
```

Now the problem is i don't really know how this thing works, is it safe to export a certificate and let others use the cURL with it or the certificate has some of my own info (Users/Password/Activity etc..) when exported thru my browser?

**SOLVED:** This is the guide i was using for those who will find this topic later: [LINK](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) and the Certificate i was talking about is from `Facebook`.

:)

Comment: Where do you have your certificate *from?*

Comment: The Certificate is from Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends. *Server* HTTPS certificates are global, and so are CA certificates (which is what you seem to be after). These are used by the client to verify that it's talking to the correct server securely.

On the other hand, it is possible for the server to verify a *client-side* certificate, to verify "who is the user" (that does not seem to be the case here).

Comment: This is the guide I'm after [LINK](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) and the Certificate is from `Facebook` i just want to be sure :)

Comment: @Ricardo: You might want to add that as an answer :) Yes, those certificates are public and don't contain any personal information.